# Set default selected item on drop down box

Tags: jquery

I need to set first selected item as index 1 of the drop down box.How can I do that ?

I have tried something like below.But I need to do that without using hard coded values (i.e. without 'Day Camp').

```
 //for set default values
                    $("#ddlServiceCategoryType option").each(function () {
                        if ($(this).text() == 'Day Camp') {
                            $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
```

[image]

**HTML**

```
<select id="ddlServiceCategoryType" name="ServiceCategoryTypeViewModel.ServiceCategoryType.Id" class="has_sb" style="display: block;"><option value="">-Please select a service category-</option>
<option value="1">Day Camp</option>
<option value="2">Boarding</option>
<option value="3">Pet Sitting</option>
<option value="4">Grooming</option>
</select>
```

Comment: can you share the html for the select

Comment: Have you tried `$("#ddlServiceCategoryType option").first().attr('selected', 'selected')")` ?

Comment: Create http://jsfiddle.net/hA423/2/ and share your code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
$("#ddlServiceCategoryType").val(function () {
    return $(this).find('option:eq(1)').attr('value')
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5eZXx/)

Comment: @Sampath please share the relevant html then'

Comment: @Sampath also how is the dynamic items added where this code is executed

Comment: Updated. Plz check that.

Answer (score 4):

If its always default and never changes, is there any reason you can't do it in HTML?

```
<option selected="selected">
```

Comment: Cannot do this way,hence data is coming from db dynamically through ajax call.

Comment: Arun has your answer then!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understood the question correctly. But you can use the below if your need is to set the first `option` as default selected.

```
$('#ddlServiceCategoryType').each(function () {
    $(this).find('option:first').prop('selected', true);
});
```

Or, if the first `option` is always `-Please select a service category-` and you want to set the next option as default selected, use the below:

```
$('#ddlServiceCategoryType').each(function () {
    $(this).find('option').eq(1).prop('selected', true);
});
```

Comment: Yep,Your 2nd solution is working.But performance wise it's bad.B'cos it iterates through all the items of ddl. Any way +1 for the support.

Comment: @Sampath: Ah, understand. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

you can do it as follows:

```
$("#ddlServiceCategoryType option").each(function (k,v) {
 if (k === 1) {
    $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
    return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
if ($(this).prop('selectedIndex') == 1) {
       $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
       return false;
    }
```

Comment: can you explain where the problem is.

Comment: `prop` is not compatible with IE.  Should use `attr` instead.